# Fluent NHibernate map GUID type property NOT Identity

Tags: c#, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping, guid

I have a guid property in my entity and i want to map it to guid field in MS SQL.

```
 public class SomeEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Guid GUID { get; set; }
    }
```

and how can i map this to table and allow MS SQL generate this guid field
i've tried this

```
Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
Map(x => x.GUID).Unique().Not.Insert().Not.Update();
```

with no luck. The problem is when entity has been added it generates GUID but when i select it returns empty guid(`{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}`).
also i've tried this

```
Map(x => x.GUID).Unique().ReadOnly();
```

again with no luck, so what is the solution? how to map to guid, which should be generated in MS SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my bad:

```
Map(x => x.GUID).Generated.Insert().ReadOnly();
```

works fine